# Black hole spin measurements

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics

While measurements of black hole spin of supermassive black holes in AGN using the X-ray reflection method (as shown in the figure below), 90% confidence error  bars on black hole spin and 1$\sigma$ error bars on black hole mass are chosen.

I could not understand why the error bars are chosen as such. The paper [*Observing Black Holes Spin*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11704) (Reynolds (2019)) says that this choice follows the conventions as in the relevant primary literature.

[image: spin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it is not unusual for uncertainties to be quoted at the 1$\sigma$ level in the astronomical literature (I would say it is the default unless otherwise specified), a 90% confidence interval is somewhat peculiar.

I looked at a couple of the main primary literature sources used to collect the black hole spin data for this figure. Both [Patrick et al. (2012)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012MNRAS.426.2522P/abstract) and [Walton et al. (2013)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.428.2901W/abstract) use a $\chi^2$ fitting approach and quote as uncertainties, the value of the spin parameter where the $\chi^2$ increase by 2.71 from its minimum value. This is indeed approriate (with lots of statistical caveats) for a 90% confidence interval.

I don't think there is any particular reason for this choice. They do not quote 1$\sigma$ (or 68% confidence) uncertainties and it is unsafe to assume that there is any fixed ratio between a 90% and 68% confidence interval.

Given these are two of the major sources of data for the plot you show from Reynolds' review, I don't think there was any alternative other than to show the data and error bars as they were given in those papers.